# JQuery .button() method does nothing

Tags: jquery, methods, radio-button

I'm attempting to skin a radio button with JQuery UI's .button() method.

Here's the code for the button:

```
    <input value name="U1" id="U1:1" type="radio" class="languageWidget">
```

And here is the corresponding Javascript:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("input.languageWidget").button();
    });
```

I'm not getting any kind of console errors and the page still loads fine.  It simply does not reskin the button.  Any clues?

Comment: What is it supposed to do? There is no such method http://api.jquery.com/

Comment: jQuery doesn't have a button method, did you include jQuery UI?

Comment: Do you have a failing fiddle? Are all the CSS and image assets loading? Do you have the jQuery UI library loading correctly? Do any other JQUI functions work?

Comment: I did mean JQuery UI, I apologize, and yes the UI library loaded.  It's odd because when I go to select a little more generally I can see the method styling other elements.  It's just this one element it seems unhappy with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For radio buttons it's a little more complex (but not too much).

First, you need a DIV that contains the button set, which you initialize all-at-once with the buttonset() method.

Next, you need to have a `<label for="this_button_id">`, because it is the label that becomes visible and clickable. Therefore, with a radio button, the label becomes the button, not the input control.

So you must ensure that the `<input>` element's ID and the `<label>` element's `for=` match.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h6Kva/)

---

```
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('#testdiv').buttonset();

            }); //END $(document).ready() 

        </script>
    </head>
<body>

<!--<input name="U1" id="U1-1" type="radio" class="languageWidget" />-->
<div id="testdiv">
    <input type="radio" id="U1-1" name="U1-1" /><label for="U1-1">Choice 1</label>
    <input type="radio" id="U1-2" name="U1-2" checked="checked" /><label for="U1-2">Choice 2</label>
    <input type="radio" id="U1-3" name="U1-3" /><label for="U1-3">Choice 3</label>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```